# JavaScript character (£) not displaying instead showing '�'

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I am using google maps API, on certain markers there is an info box pop up the contents of which is pulled from a cell in a mysql database. Some of these cells contain the pound symbol (£) but when it is displayed in the info box it is replaced with a '�'. MySQL is set to 'utf8_general_ci' and my page has charset=UTF-8 in its head why wont it display this character?

Comment: I suspect you'll find your site isn't using UTF-8 as you expect. Are you able to link to a live copy?

Comment: unfortunately im still in the early stages of developing and im doing it locally, i have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> within the head of my page is this not set correctly? (as you may have figured im new to the whole web design business so im sure it is probably a very obvious rookie mistake but im really struggling to bottom this as ive already set everything i am aware of to uft-8 :/

Comment: First, make sure the symbol is stored correctly in your database. A good way to do this is to use phpMyAdmin and view the record there. That content type looks correct, but check to see what your browser thinks the page is - in Firefox, use "View Page Info" and check what the Encoding is (other browsers should have equivalents).

Comment: I am using PHPmyadmin to manage my database so the character was first input into MySQL through PHPmyadmin and is still showing correctly. Thank you though all insights are greatly recieved as im still very much learning, do you have any further thoughts about where i might have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you try checking the page encoding as understood by your browser? Secondly, grab the source from View Source, paste it [on a pasteboard](http://pastie.org/) and ping me the link.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your php page is truly sending utf8 headers, and that your database (or the relevant table(s) — important) is using the utf8 charset. One or the other probably using some other charset (windows-iso or swedish-latin respectively).

It may also be that you've non-utf8 data stored in an utf8 sql table, or vice-versa. In that case you need to [convert it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets). In essence:

1. Convert the relevant fields to binary text
2. Change the charset
3. Convert the text back to text

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- HTML entities:

  - `&pound;`
  - `&#163;`
  - `&#x00A3;`
- Unicode javascript:

  - `\u00A3`

But check it better, because if your code is encoded in UTF8 and is parsed as UTF8, it should work well using `£`.